# See the number of comments in a Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

How can I see the number of comments made on a Google Doc?
Apart from manually counting them, of course...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to your document
2. In the address/url/search box of your web browser replace the `edit` from the document URL with `mobilebasic`
3. The comments will be numbered with letters.

Let a = 1, b = 2 and so on...

4. Go to the last comment.

If it has two letters:

Multiply the first number by 26 then add the second number.

Take `[ad]`:

```
1 * 26 = 26 + 4 = 30
```

That is the total comment number.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
What do you mean by "Replace the edit at the end with mobilebasic" - what edit? End of what?

Comment: @WilliamHackett-Jones the URL of the document will have a / at the end or edit. Either add mobilebasic to the end or replace edit with mobilebasic

Comment: @WilliamHackett-Jones  no problem. If my answer helped please press the tick next to my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, /mobilebasic does not display any of the comments anymore.

Comment: You sir, just saved me a whole lot of time, thanks! 

This does work still, you get little blue `[xx]` notes wherever a comment was attached. If you go to the last comment note and click it, the URL will change to something like `/mobilebasic#cmnt176`, at least for me that 176 matches up with the `[ft] = (26*6)+20`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, without the remedial math, is to export them to a spreadsheet, which will also allow filtering. To do this, install the Comments Exporter Add-On, open the document with comments and create an export:

[image]

Then open the exported spreadsheet and it will be easier to count all comments (regardless of whether they have been closed or deleted):

[image]