# Count the number of suggestions in a Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Similar to [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168332/290565) question, I would like to count the number of suggestions (not comments) a Google Docs has. The first answer of that question doesn't work for resolved comments, and neither works for suggestions. I would like to see how many total suggestions and/or comments a Google Doc received, all of which are now resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out an answer!

On a web browser, go to the Docs file. Press the comment icon to open the comments and suggestions panel; looks like this:

[image: comments icon]

Open Developer Tools (usually F12). In console, type the following: `$('#docos-stream-view').childElementCount`. The number that pops out is the total number of suggestions + comments (replies not counted).

#### Explanation

The command above is basically selecting the comments panel (using jQuery) and counting the number of HTML DIVs it contains. This is the number of comments/suggestions!

Comment: if people are looking to filter out the resolved comments, click the 'all types' drop down and select open. the js will still work to output the number of open comments you have